# Tried to use the environment variable in graphql codegen file

Tags: reactjs, graphql, yaml, environment-variables, codegen

I tried to use the environment variable in the codegen.yml. I decided to generate the codegen.yml file by using the handlebars.

```
yarn add handlebars
```

**codegen-template.yml**

```
overwrite: true
generates:
  ./src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    schema: "{{REACT_APP_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT}}"
    documents: src/**/*.graphql
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "generate-yaml": "npx handlebars -c .env -i codegen-template.yml -o codegen.yml"
}
```

and run

```
yarn generate-yaml
```

Got the below error

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ npx handlebars -c .env.qa -i codegen-template.yml -o codegen.yml

/Users/test/Documents/Workspace/cr/node_modules/handlebars/bin/handlebars:110
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Unable to open template file "codegen.yml"
    at /Users/test/Documents/Workspace/cr/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/precompiler.js:104:25
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
  description: undefined,
  fileName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined,
  endLineNumber: undefined,
  number: undefined
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

How to resolve this issue.